# Topics about the deal.II finite element library class "SparsityPattern"

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, data-storage, deal.ii

When learning the deal.II FE library, I am a bit confused about the mechanism of its "SparsityPattern" class. Through reading the documentation, I only got to know that it uses the Compressed Row Storage format to store indices of nonzero entries of a sparse matrix.

To put my confusion be explicit, suppose I have a quare 10x10 sparse matrix which stores the values corresponding to 10 degrees of freedom, namely `dof_handler.n_dofs = 10`:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 &  0 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0\\
3 & 4 & 5 &  0 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0\\
0 & 6 & 7 &  8 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 15 & 16 & 17 & 0  & 0  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 18 & 19 & 20 & 0  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 21 & 22 & 23 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 &  0  & 24 & 25 & 26\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 &  0  & 0  & 27 & 28\\
\end{pmatrix}

But at first, suppose we don't know exactly where the nonzero entries are and can only get a maximal estimate of their number at each row, say `max_per_row`, and let `max_per_row = 5`. Then the sparsity pattern would be:

\begin{pmatrix}
X & X & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & X & X & X\\
X & X & X & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & X & X\\
X & X & X & X & X & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & X & X & X & X & X & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & X & X & X & X & X & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & X & X & X & X & X & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & X & X & X & X & X & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & X & X & X & X & X\\
X & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & X & X & X & X\\
X & X & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & X & X & X\\
\end{pmatrix}

One way to get the sparsitypattern is:

```
SparsityPattern  sparsity_pattern;
sparsity_pattern.reinit(10, 10, 5);
DoFTools::make_sparsity_pattern(dof_handler, sparsity_pattern);
sparsity_pattern.compress()
```

where `dof_handler` stores the information of degrees of freedom.

And it can also be implemented as below:

```
DynamicSparsityPattern dynamic_pattern (dof_handler.n_dofs());
DoFTools::make_sparsity_pattern (dof_handler, dynamic_pattern);
constraints.condense (dynamic_pattern);
SparsityPattern sp;
sp.copy_from (dynamic_pattern);
```

So, my question is:

*1) Here, when we call `sparsity_pattern.reinit(10, 10, 5)`, does it create an empty 10x10 matrix (2D vector) or just a 1x100 vector storing the values row by row? And if it is 10x10 or 1x100, then what is the functionality of third parameter `max_per_row=5`?

*2) I think `sparsity_pattern.reinit(10, 10, 5)` creates a 10x10 matrix and then using `DoFTools::make_sparsity_pattern(dof_handler, sparsity_pattern)` to create a CRS format, i.e, two vectors storing the row columm index of nonzero entries at each row and the index starting a new row respectively, according to the dof information stored in `dof_handler`. Does this understanding make sense?

*3) I know in C++ STL, we can compress a vector to its actuall capacity using its member function `vector.shrink_to_fit`. But here if `DoFTools::make_sparsity_pattern` has already make a compressed format of 5 entries at each row (according to *2), how can it be compressed again using `sparsity_pattern.compress()`?

*4) Does `DynamicSparsityPattern dynamic_pattern (dof_handler.n_dofs())` creates a `(n_dofs) x (n_dofs)` matrix, then what's the difference between `DoFTools::make_sparsity_pattern(dof_handler, sparsity_pattern)` and `DoFTools::make_sparsity_pattern (dof_handler, dynamic_pattern)`.

*5) What about `constraints.condense (dynamic_pattern)`?

*6) In C++ STL, we know that we can copy a vector `v1` of size 4, capacity 8 to a vector `v2`, then `v2` will be of capacity 4. In this way, can can also compress a vector to its actuall capacity. Is it the same mechanism to use `sp.copy_from (dynamic_pattern)'?

I know these questions are so dummy to experienced users of deal.II. But to green learners as me, they are really great hurdles to jump. I sincerely hope someone could be so kind to give some help, and any comments would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try answer based on my experience with deal.ii.

1. The `max_per_row=5` means that at most there will be 5 non-zeros per row in the matrix. Since we now know this then we do not need to have a $1\times{}100$ matrix but rather a $1\times{}50$. In other words this parameter sets an upper-bound on the memory needed. In reality it is not stored as one vector but rather as two: a row pointer vector and a column indicies vector in accordance with CRS format. See 2).
2. Yes the sparsity pattern holds the row pointers and the column indices as two vectors.
3. We must potentially compress again because while we set **maximum** of 5 entries per row, there may in fact be less for any given row. One row might have 5 while a different row might only have 3. This results in extra entries in the column index vector that should be removed by compression. Note that these extra entries in the column index vector are often written as $-1$'s since a column index can never be negative and thus if it is $-1$ we know that no non-zero has been assigned for that column index.
4. As the [documentation](https://www.dealii.org/8.3.0/doxygen/deal.II/classDynamicSparsityPattern.html) says the `DynamicSparsityPattern` is used to find the sparsity pattern while being compressed at all times. This reduces memory overhead at the expense of cpu time.

> This class acts as an intermediate form of the SparsityPattern class. From the interface it mostly represents a SparsityPattern object that is kept compressed at all times. However, since the final sparsity pattern is not known while constructing it, keeping the pattern compressed at all times can only be achieved at the expense of either increased memory or run time consumption upon use. The main purpose of this class is to avoid some memory bottlenecks, so we chose to implement it memory conservative. The chosen data format is too unsuited to be used for actual matrices, though. It is therefore necessary to first copy the data of this object over to an object of type SparsityPattern before using it in actual matrices.
>
> Another viewpoint is that this class does not need up front allocation of a certain amount of memory, but grows as necessary. An extensive description of sparsity patterns can be found in the documentation of the Sparsity patterns module.

5. The [documentation](https://www.dealii.org/8.3.0/doxygen/deal.II/classConstraintMatrix.html#a4c543aa9c09a2eeb1f6c89fcd6e67f0c) has this to say:

> Condense a sparsity pattern. The name of the function mimics the name of the function we use to condense linear systems, but it is a bit of a misnomer for the current context. This is because in the context of linear systems, we eliminate certain rows and columns of the linear system, i.e., we "reduce" or "condense" the linear system. On the other hand, in the current context, the functions does not remove nonzero entries from the sparsity pattern. Rather, it adds those nonzero entry locations to the sparsity pattern that will later be needed for the process of condensation of constrained degrees of freedom from a linear system.
>
> Since this function adds new nonzero entries to the sparsity pattern, the given sparsity pattern must not be compressed. The constraint matrix (i.e., the current object) must be closed. The sparsity pattern is compressed at the end of the function.

6. We copy the `DynamicSparsityPattern` to a regular `SparsityPattern` using the copy call because apparently the dynamic one isn't in a nice enough format for later operations. How this is done internally may involve vector copies as you suggest but I am not sure.

**Concrete Example**

Lets run through your first `SparsityPattern` code snippet (keeping in mind that the exact details of how this is done in deal.ii might differ, but the basic idea I think is correct.)

```
SparsityPattern  sparsity_pattern;
sparsity_pattern.reinit(10, 10, 5);
DoFTools::make_sparsity_pattern(dof_handler, sparsity_pattern);
sparsity_pattern.compress()
```

1. Call `SparsityPattern  sparsity_pattern;`. This just creates our sparsity pattern object with default constructor. The `sparsity_pattern` object contains member variables like `row` and `col` both of which are vectors (currently of size 0). Note: `row` and `col` are names I made up. They are called something else in deal.ii.
2. Call `sparsity_pattern.reinit(10, 10, 5);`. Our sparsity pattern initializes the row pointer and column index vectors. This might look something like: `row.resize(10+1,0);` and `col.resize(10*5,-1);`
3. Call `make_sparsity_pattern`. This determines where the non-zeros in our sparse matrix will be, however **some** of the `col` entries will still be `-1`'s - i.e. cases where there was less then 5 non-zeros in the row. Otherwise `row` is correctly filled and `col` contains both `-1`'s and other positive column indices indicating the columns where non-zeros exist.
4. Call `compress`. This compresses the `col` vector by removing any `-1`'s.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your detailed answer! It's really a great help. However, as to your third point, I might disagree with it. At the time I call `sparcity_pattern.compress()`, information about the actual nonzero length at each row is in fact still unknown. Then how can it determine the extent to compress, based on what?

Comment: @David406 You call `make_sparsity_pattern` first and then you compress. Once you have called `make_sparsity_pattern` you know exactly where the non-zeros will be.

Comment: Thank you so much, @James. Your additional explanation on the concrete example are awesome and almost clarifies everything. Could you please also give some comments on the second example of DynimicSparsityPattern to explain how it can be kept being compressed at all times? YOUR EFFORTS ARE GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: @David The `DynamicSparsityPattern` is the same idea except that there is no `compress` call after since this sparsity pattern is always compressed. How the `DynamicSparsityPattern` remains compressed when we call `make_sparsity_pattern` is not really important for the user to know. I am guessing it does this by many copying of vectors internally but the actual implementation details aren't really important.